# How to align top nav bar with wrapper

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this so apologies for any bad formatting and wrong terminology.

I'm trying to create a nav bar at the top of a page and have it the same width as my wrapper which is 1000px. I managed to get it to the center once but it didn't align with my wrapper and I cant even recreate that.

Any help at all would be appreciated, even if it doesn't directly answer my question

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="navtest.css">
    </head>
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <nav class="topnav">
                    <ul class="topnavlist">
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 3</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 4</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 5</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <p>Main Text</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.topnavlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

.topnavlink {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.topnavlink:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 1000px;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Try using "width.. position .. margin" from the wrapper also in the navbar css class

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```css
.topnavlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

.topnavlink {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;

}

.topnavlink:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

header {
    margin:0 auto;
    top: 0;
    width: 1000px;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
html
css
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="navtest.css">
    </head>
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <nav class="topnav">
                    <ul class="topnavlist">
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 3</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 4</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 5</a></li>
                        <li><a class="topnavlink">Menu 6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <main>
            <div>
                <p>Main Text</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
header {
    margin:0 auto;
    top: 0;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

This part of the code was interfering with the positioning of the nav bar, removing it fixed the issue and didn't cause any other problems.

Comment: This isn't an answer (obviously); if you want to say "thank you" then respond in the comments section, by clicking on the "Add a comment" link below the comment(s). While you don't have the privilege to comment everywhere (yet), you can always comment on your own questions, and answers (both your answers to other questions, and answers others post to your own questions).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).